# How does wso2 manage scopes?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm having a hard time creating scopes and assigning them my web app (the client/service provider).
It seems to me that, wso2 does not handle scopes the way it's supposed to.

**What I want**
Assigning a few scopes, such as myapi:read and myapi:write, to a client/machine.
The client requests a token asking for those scopes.
Wso2 should include the scopes in the token if it has been configured to do so.

**What I understood**
According to a [wso2 presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IL5OA9WPWpE), it does it in a non-conventional way and applies only to human users:

- Create a scope via wso2 api(in this case, myapi:write) and bind it to a role
- Assign that role to the user
- Enable scope based validator in oidc configuration for the service provider

In case of code flow, it would work since the role is mapped to the user. However, if it's client credentials, my app wouldn't be able to get that scope unless i can assign a role to it (without the human user).

I might have missed something and perhaps, it is possible to include scopes in client credentials flows. I just don't know how exactly. I haven't seen anything in wso2 documentation.

Comment: Follow these steps: https://wso2.com/library/articles/2017/01/article-an-overview-of-scope-management-with-wso2-api-manager/#:~:text=A%20scope%20allows%20you%20to,what%20resources%20it%20can%20access.